# SharePoint Online - AppInv

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Trying to create a cross-domain javascript call that will access data via the sp online api.

I've done the appregnew successfully, getting back confirmation that my client id and secret etc was generated.

I go next to appinv, and go to the appid field.  Press the lookup button, and it just refreshes the page, with no details.  Tried this with 2 different browsers (edge/chrome).

Any suggestions?  Have not done this before.

Comment: Is there any updates ? Did you fill the valid App Id and then click Lookup button to get the details ?

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT - i got distracted by something else, have to look at this

Comment: never mind , if you have time to try, please update the post. :)

Comment: i accepted, it worked...thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it's working and if it's working, you could accept the post below as answer, so it could be also helpful to others in the forum. :)

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT - sorry - forgot to hit accept button

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please fill the client id of created app in the inputbox and then click Lookup button:

[image]

Then title, App Domain and Redirect URL will be filled automatically.